# Application for gathering real-time data from sensors and composing multiple sources of data

Tags: stream, real-time, visualization, iot

I'm currently searching for an application to visualize data from different sensors. The idea is that the sensor picks up movement and sends the angle which the object is at to the application. With about 4 of these sensors, they should display movement at their vicinity.
An example would be a car driving on a street. On both sides of the street there are sensors which pick up the angle(if the car was right in front of you, the angle would be 90 degrees) and send it to the application. Then the application should be able to take the input information from the sensors and plot a moving car/object on a canvas.
So far i've found Power BI / Azure IoT hub and cumulocity which although gather sensor data, but do not have the ways to transform it into  the earlier specified form.
Is there anything which is capable of this?

Comment: What sort of delay is acceptable in your "real-time" display ?  I've done something similar recently using Python > Snowflake > Tableau and the delay could be a few minutes, but if you want something closer to almost REAL time I would be playing with Python or something similar directly to make the display faster

Comment: The delay should be maximum few seconds and I need rather commercial applications to find, but thanks anyways.